# Possible to refinish pressed-wood cabinets?

Tags: wood, cabinets

I've got some kitchen cabinets. The wood is very lightweight and the cross-section is pressed wood with what looks like a durable paper-like surface layer. I'm not sure what they're called. They were new and installed recently (in the past year), I'm just not quite satisfied with the color. Is it possible to use something like the new [Rustoleum product](http://cabinets.rustoleumtransformations.com/) to change the finish? And what is the Rustoleum stuff? Is it like paint? is it a stain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cabinets are probably a melamine covered press particle board type. You should be able to use the Rustoleum product you mentioned in your question.  You could also paint them.  What you cannot do is sand and stain them because there is no real wood veneer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this on a bathroom cabinet once.  I sanded with 220 grit after fixing small damage with wood putty, primed, painted; all with an air compressor and spray gun for a great finish.  It would not peel, but it would scrape off easy with harsh contact.  It think if you sand blasted, it would be better, but who is gonna do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a utility knife and cut out the old (bubbled up) section, sanded and
repaired it with just joint compound. It took a few coats but after the primer and 
2 coats of paint, they all look just like new.